# Pellet reasoning over XML Literals

Tags: jena, pellet

I am using Pellet reasoner with Jena. I inserted some data into a TDB store. I have also schema ontology in a file and Jena rules as well. I layered the Generic rule reasoner and Pellet. However, am getting inconsistent ontology error due to literal datatypes, yet the inserted data has same datatype with the schema definition. My data:

```
     <rdf:RDF
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:resource="http://www.cs.kaist.ac.kr/medication/resource#"
        xmlns:time="http://www.w3.org/2006/time#"
        xmlns:medication="http://www.cs.kaist.ac.kr/medication/ontology#"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" > 
         .......
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.cs.kaist.ac.kr/medication/resource#TimeDesc300">
         <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2006/time#TimeDescription"/>
         <time:hour rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">3</time:hour>
         <time:year rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">2014</time:year>
         <time:month rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">8</time:month>
         <time:day rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">26</time:day>
         <time:minute rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">0</time:minute>
         <time:second rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal">0</time:second>
       </rdf:Description>
       .......
```

The reasoner:

```
    .......
    TDBConnection connection = new TDBConnection();
    connection.getDataset().begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
    Model dataTDB = connection.getDataset().getDefaultModel();

    /*OntModel ontology = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    ontology.read("data//medtimeOnto.owl");*/

     Model ontMedical = FileManager.get().loadModel("data//medtimeOnto.owl");
     ontMedical.add(FileManager.get().loadModel("data//myOwnTimeFinal.owl"));

      OntModel ontology = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC, 
     ontMedical );      

    //Reasoner owlReasoner = (Reasoner) ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
    //InfModel owlInfModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(owlReasoner, ontology, dataTDB);

    List <Rule> rules= Rule.rulesFromURL("data//testrule.rules");           
    GenericRuleReasoner ruleReasoner = new GenericRuleReasoner(rules);          

    InfModel ruleInfModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(ruleReasoner, ontology,dataTDB);

    Reasoner pelletReasoner = PelletReasonerFactory.theInstance().create();
    InfModel pelletInfModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(pelletReasoner, ruleInfModel);    

     ExtendedIterator<Statement> stmts = pelletInfModel.listStatements().
                                filterDrop( new   Filter<Statement>() {
            public boolean accept(Statement o) {

                return ontology.add(dataTDB).contains( o );
            }
        });
     Model deductions = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().add( new StmtIteratorImpl( stmts ));
        deductions.write( System.out);
```

The error am getting:

```
     ............

     Realizing finished in 00:00
     Exception in thread "main" org.mindswap.pellet.exceptions.InconsistentOntologyException: 
     Cannot do reasoning with inconsistent ontologies!
     Reason for inconsistency: Literal value "2014"^^integer does not belong to datatype integer
     at org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.ensureConsistency(KnowledgeBase.java:2076)
     at org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.isSameAs(KnowledgeBase.java:2973)
     at rg.mindswap.pellet.jena.graph.query.GraphQueryHandler$94.contains
        (GraphQueryHandler.java:1457)
    at org.mindswap.pellet.jena.graph.query.GraphQueryHandler.containsTriple
      (GraphQueryHandler.java:1554)
    at org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletInfGraph.containsTriple(PelletInfGraph.java:472)
    at org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletInfGraph.graphBaseContains(PelletInfGraph.java:319)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.impl.GraphBase.contains(GraphBase.java:301)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.contains(ModelCom.java:1207)
    at com.kaist.medserver.MyReasoner$1.accept(MyReasoner.java:63)
    at com.kaist.medserver.MyReasoner$1.accept(MyReasoner.java:1)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.FilterDropIterator.accept(FilterDropIterator.java:33)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.FilterIterator.hasNext(FilterIterator.java:55)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.WrappedIterator.hasNext(WrappedIterator.java:90)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.Map1Iterator.hasNext(Map1Iterator.java:48)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.IteratorCollection.iteratorToList(IteratorCollection.java:63)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.GraphUtil.add(GraphUtil.java:165)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.add(ModelCom.java:197)
    at com.kaist.medserver.MyReasoner.main(MyReasoner.java:66)
```

Answer (score 0):

time:year an xsd:gYear? Not an xsd:intger (or derived type).

And time:month is a gMonth, time:day is gDay

http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-time/#summary

Comment: Originally, I used gYear,gMonth and gDay datatypes. I inserted the data using createTypedLiteral(String, RDFDatatype), but this method creates everything as integer even though i used XSDDatatype.XSDgYear,XSDgMonth and XSDgDay. So, i changed the properties on the schema to integer, but still the problem didn't go.